# How to use .each and blur to determine if there's a value before sending to textarea box?

Tags: jquery

Ok, I have really confused myself.

We have this app that concates values and sends them to TA box. I want to determine if the field has a value in it first,

- if it does have a value, add it to TA field
- if it does not have a value/empty, do not add it to the
  TA field,

**How do i do this?**

I want to use this on the **blur** event[**see code example**]. I know I need to use **.each()**, check length and/or look into each field, see if there is a value, if there is, put in TA field

**Could someone show me how to accomplish this please?**

**jsfiddle >>** http://jsfiddle.net/justmelat/6JHRT/

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="Paul"/></p>
    <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"  id="lastname" value="Ryan" /></p>
<p>Street #: <input type="text" name="street_number"  id="street_number" value="4605"/></p>
<p>Address: <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></p>
<p>State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/><br />

<span id="myzip">Zip:</span> <input type="text" name="zip"  id="zip" />
<br /><br />
<select name="hometype" id="hometype">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="SFH">Single Family Home</option>
<option value="Condo">Condo</option>
<option value="Trailer">Trailer</option><br />
</select><br />
<input type="radio" name="ownership" value="own" /> Own
<input type="radio" name="ownership" value="rent" /> Rent
    <hr />
<span id="allInfo">All Info:</span> <textarea id="ta_holdAll" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><div id="charCnt"></div><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Add to Field" id="addField">
</form>​
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function combineFields(event) {
      var mytextareaFld = $('#ta_holdAll');
      var fld_1 = $('#firstname').attr('name')+':  '+$('#firstname').val();
      var fld_2 = $('#lastname').attr('name')+':  '+$('#lastname').val();
      var fld_3 = $('#street_number').attr('name')+':  '+$('#street_number').val();
        var hold_all_fields = fld_1 +'\n' + fld_2 +'\n' + fld_3;
      //hold_all_fields.each();
      mytextareaFld.val(fld_1 +'\n' + fld_2 +'\n' + fld_3);
  }

    $('#addField').on('click',combineFields);

    $('#allInfo').on('click',function(event){
        combineFields(event);
        var $mytextareaFld = $('#ta_holdAll');
        var $outPutCount = $("#charCnt");
        var $ofText = " characters of 1000 remaining";
        var val = $mytextareaFld.val();
        var val2 = $outPutCount.text(val.length).append("<strong>"+$ofText+"</strong>");
    });

    $("#firstname,#lastname, #street_number").blur(combineFields);
});
```

​

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in the textarea if, for instance, the lastname is blank?

Comment: if lastname is blank, then nothing should appear for that item, no label, nothing.  So if some entered firstname and address, then only those two would show in the TA box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -- just check if the field exists (has length), and if it doesn't, use an empty string:

```
function combineFields(event) {
    var mytextareaFld = $('#ta_holdAll');
    var fld_1 = $('#firstname').val().length ? $('#firstname').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#firstname').val() + '\n' : '';
    var fld_2 = $('#lastname').val().length ? $('#lastname').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#lastname').val() + '\n' : '';
    var fld_3 = $('#street_number').val().length ? $('#street_number').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#street_number').val() + '\n' : '';
    var hold_all_fields = fld_1 + fld_2 + fld_3;
    mytextareaFld.val(hold_all_fields);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JHRT/3/

For added usefulness, use `jQuery.trim()` to wipe out blank spaces:

```
function combineFields(event) {
    var mytextareaFld = $('#ta_holdAll');
    var fld_1 = $.trim($('#firstname').val()).length ? $('#firstname').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#firstname').val() + '\n' : '';
    var fld_2 = $.trim($('#lastname').val()).length ? $('#lastname').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#lastname').val() + '\n' : '';
    var fld_3 = $.trim($('#street_number').val()).length ? $('#street_number').attr('name') + ':  ' + $('#street_number').val() + '\n' : '';
    var hold_all_fields = fld_1 + fld_2 + fld_3;
    mytextareaFld.val(hold_all_fields);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JHRT/4/

Comment: THANK YOU - I can't believe it was that simple.  You have no idea how much code I started with - that obviously was not working.  THANKS again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    function combineFields(event) {
        $('#ta_holdAll').val('');
        $("#firstname,#lastname, #street_number").each(function(){
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
               var val = $(this).attr('name')+':  '+$(this).val();
               var mytextareaFld = $('#ta_holdAll');
              mytextareaFld.val(mytextareaFld.val() + val + '\n');
            }
        })
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JHRT/7/